# Google CloudDNS browser error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have 3 domains set up with Google CloudDNS, but only one of them is resolving.

The a records for the apex dns names are pointing to wwwizer forwarding service, and the www dns names are cnamed to my hosting buckets at  c.storage.googleapis.com.

The buckets are publicly shared and website configuration is done.

However, the browser returns ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVE, and I can't even ping two of the pages.

host -t cname returns domain "is an alias for c.storage.googleapis.com" for the working domain's, "not found: 2(SERVFAIL)" for the second domain's, and "not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)" for the third domain's www.

dig +short however returns "c.storage.googleapis.com.
storage.l.googleusercontent.com.
216.58.213.240" for all three domains.

As far as I know, CNAME records don't have propagation delays, so I am confused what is causing the DNS resolving issues. Any experts around who  could lend a helping hand?

Alex

edit: The pages were resolving intermittently first, now stable. Obviously cname propagation delays may happen if you use GCS, and you just need to always wait that hour longer.

Comment: Any changes on the DNS level have propagation delay. By looking at the edit that you have on the question, it looks like the issue is resolved. If so, is it possible to post the answer so others can benefit from it? More information about DNS propagation can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/dns/overview#propagation_of_changes

Answer (score 1):

The pages were resolving intermittently first, now stable. Obviously cname propagation delays may happen if you use GCS, and you just need to always wait that hour longer.